# Why in_array doesn't work on array that was created using loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Why `in_array` not work on array that create from loop php ?

this below code show `Match found`.

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    $people[] = $i;
}    
if (in_array('test', $people))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
?>
```

and this below code show `Match not found`.

```
<?php
$people = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
if (in_array('test', $people))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
?>
```

How to solve first code to show `Match not found`

Comment: try using strict checking `in_array('test', $people, true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just change

```
$people[] = $i; ---by--> $people[] = "$i";
```

Then you compare strings

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    $people[] = "$i";

}   

if (in_array('test', $people))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

Because in your first array you have integers and by default [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) does a [non-strict type comparison](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_operators.c#1840), which has only a [limited amount of type pairs](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_operators.c#compare_function) which it takes into consideration. So it will do a silent cast to an integer with your needle, which results in 0 and it finds it in the array.

To avoid this error, just pass `TRUE` as 3rd argument to `in_array()` so it does a [strict type comparison](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_operators.c#1788), e.g.

```
if (in_array('test', $people, TRUE))
```

Comment: yes and no ;-) "by default in_array() won't check the type of the elements" That is not correct. The default comparison function for non-strict comparison still takes the types into account. But it has a rather limited amount of type-pairs it considers. And the default is to convert both operands to numbers => `test`->0 === 0  :-S

Comment: why still show `Match not found` when use code ?

`<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    $people[] = $i;
}    
if (in_array('5', $people, TRUE))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
?>`

Comment: @mongmongseesee Because now you do a strict comparison and `"5" !== 5`

Comment: @VolkerK rewrote it and linked to the actual source code comparison functions.

Comment: @VolkerK ascii arrows are so outdated ;) use [unicode arrows](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html)

Comment: I'm three months from turning 40, bare me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You've already got answers that tell you how to get around this. Let me just add a more technical answer *why* this happens....

This behaviour is rooted in the peculiar way [`ZEND_API int compare_function(..)`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.17/Zend/zend_operators.c#L1599) works.
When you call [`in_array(needle, haystack, strict)`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.17/ext/standard/array.c#L1214) without $strict=true this [function is used](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.17/ext/standard/array.c#L1184) to [compare](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.17/Zend/zend_operators.c#L1840) `needle` with every element in haystack until a match is found.
Your needle is a string and the elements in haystack are integers.
Let's take a(n abbreviated) look at `compare_function()`

```
while(1) {
    switch (TYPE_PAIR(Z_TYPE_P(op1), Z_TYPE_P(op2))) {
        case TYPE_PAIR(IS_LONG, IS_LONG):
            ZVAL_LONG(result, Z_LVAL_P(op1)>Z_LVAL_P(op2)?1:(Z_LVAL_P(op1)<Z_LVAL_P(op2)?-1:0));
                return SUCCESS;
        [...more CASEs that don't apply on the first iteration of the while-loop...]
        default:
          [...some if-elseif cases that do not apply on the first iteration of the while-loop...]
                } else {
                    zendi_convert_scalar_to_number(op1, op1_copy, result);
                    zendi_convert_scalar_to_number(op2, op2_copy, result);
                    converted = 1;
                }
[...]
```

when this code is exectued for the first time `op1 ~ 'test'` and `op2~0`.
( ~ meaning "roughly is", because the internal represenation is a little bit different, but it doesn't really matter here.)
But there is no case for the TYPE_PAIR(IS_STRING, IS_LONG), so it hits the default: branch. There are some if-conditions for handling objects, but neither operand is an object, so it get's to the part where the operands are converted (once).
Again no if-conditon applies, so it hits the last else-branch which converts *both* operands into numbers.
`'test'` gets converted to `0` and `0` stays `0`.
Then the while-loop is executed again, now with the TYPE_PAIR(IS_LONG,IS_LONG) - the very first case. And *now* both operands are equal -> in_array() returns true.

...and yes, I find that confusing, too ;-)